# Can I mount the root (system) filesystem as writable in Big Sur?

Tags: macos, big-sur

After updating to big sur, I can no longer mount the root as writable (even with SIP disabled):

```bsh
sudo mount -uw /
mount_apfs: volume could not be mounted: Permission denied
mount: / failed with 66
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by mounting root?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

DISCLAIMER: have a good backup and plan to [erase and reinstall](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208496) your Mac from the internet before trying this procedure. A mistake can prevent your system from starting without assistance.

1. Disable FileVault
2. Reboot into recovery mode and run:

   ```bsh
   csrutil authenticated-root disable
   ```
3. Reboot back into MacOS
4. Find your root mount's device - run `mount` and chop off the last s, e.g. if your root is `/dev/disk1s2s3`, you'll mount `/dev/disk1s2`
5. Create a new directory, for example `~/mount`

   ```
   mkdir -p -m777 ~/mount
   ```
6. Run `sudo mount -o nobrowse -t apfs DISK_PATH MOUNT_PATH`, using the values from above

   ```
   sudo mount -o nobrowse -t apfs /dev/disk1s2 ~/mount
   ```
7. Modify the files under the mounted directory
8. Run `sudo bless --folder MOUNT_PATH/System/Library/CoreServices --bootefi --create-snapshot`
9. Reboot your system, and the changes will take place

Comment: `DISK_PATH`is `/dev/disk1s2`, `MOUNT_PATH` is `~/mount`, I assume?

Comment: **WARNING If you follow these instructions you will not be able to reenable FileVault!**

Comment: How is this managed to work? You cannot unmount something that runs your terminal and `zsh`/ `bash` /`sh` whatever you need to run it? I cannot manage to get this working as `mount_apfs: volume could not be mounted: Resource busy` failed with 75

Comment: I'm getting exactly what @DominikBucher says on an M1 (Apple Silicon) with latest Big Sur installed. When mounting from recovery and modifying, for instance, files under `/System/Library/LaunchDaemon/` with both SIP and SSV disabled (SSV = https://eclecticlight.co/2020/06/25/big-surs-signed-system-volume-added-security-protection/), any modifications performed are not persisted once I boot back into OSX :/

Comment: Even with Big Sur 11.0.1 (not the latest), it gives `mount_apfs: volume could not be mounted: Resource busy` and fails with 75, like what @DominikBucher and @brainstorm said.

Comment: @brainstorm Like you, I was able to successfully mount r/w in recovery and modify files, but lost all the modifications when I rebooted. I think it is because step 8 (the `bless` command) fails to even create a snapshot, much less bless it. I also tried another way to create a snapshot, `/System/Library/Filesystems/apfs.fs/Contents/Resources/apfs_systemsnapshot -v <volume mount point> -r ""` from https://www.tonymacx86.com/threads/solved-disable-system-file-protection-in-big-sur.302406/ but that also gave an error, so I rebooted back without a snapshot of my changes, and lost them all ..

Comment: Interesting, related recent read about `bputil`: https://eclecticlight.co/2021/05/21/m1-secure-boot-morphine-and-self-destruction/

Comment: I'm unable to get this to work on MacOS 11.6.5. Like the previous commenter noted, creating a snapshot with bless fails: `Couldn't create snapshot on volume /Users/me/mount: Operation not permitted`

Comment: I got it to work finally. The problem was that `authenticated-root` was not properly disabled. I run MacOS in VMWare, and disabled SIP using this guide: https://itectec.com/askdifferent/how-to-disable-sip-when-big-sur-is-installed-in-a-vmware-fusion-player-virtual-machine/ but disabling `authenticated-root` was missing from the hex value stored to NVRAM. Using value ff0f0000 instead of 7f000000 did the trick.

Comment: The --folder option is only supported for external devices on Apple Silicon Macs. `% sudo bless --folder ~/mount/System/Library/CoreServices --bootefi --create-snapshot`, `bless: For Apple Silicon Macs, the 'folder' option is only supported for external devices`. But the --mount option (and the --setBoot option) seems to work. `% sudo bless --mount ~/mount/System/Library/CoreServices --setBoot --create-snapshot` [link](https://superuser.com/questions/1715785/how-to-bless-folder-as-bootable-snapshot-in-macos-12-3-1-on-an-apple-silicon-dev)

Answer (score 20):

My company requires to read/write environment informations under `/data/webapps/appenv`. Therefore, this workaround shared by a colleague of mine might not answer this question directly, but it is super useful if you want to write something under your root path!

1. Create a file: `sudo vim /etc/synthetic.conf`.
2. Write content: `<dir>⇥/System/Volumes/Data/<dir>`. **Notice**: the `⇥` is a tab!

   In my case, it looks like this:  `data⇥/System/Volumes/Data/data`
3. Go to `/System/Volumes/Data` and do `sudo mkdir <dir>`.
4. Then do `sudo chmod -R 777 <dir>`.
5. Finally, reboot, and your directory `<dir>` should now be accessible.

Comment: I don’t know why this was downvoted. Maybe because the answer is formulated in an anecdotal way, but AFAICS it points to the preferable way of creating symlinks or directories under / on Big Sur, namely “synthetic firmlinks”, see `man synthetic.conf` or https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2020/01/18/creating-root-level-directories-and-symbolic-links-on-macos-catalina/

Comment: This is the actual correct answer that solves the XY problem here

Comment: This is a solution to the problem, but not an answer to the question. So I understand it not being the top answer. Thank you though, as this solves my exact problem in a less hacky way.

Comment: I'm not sure this helps you exctaly as I don't know the reason you want writeable, but if you just one folder like me that needs rw for projects, just open "System Preferences" -> "Disk Utility" and create a volume on your disk. Very easy and painless.

Comment: Beware disinformation from posters on discussions.apple.com - see https://archive.ph/V5BWp for a bunch of misinformation on this topic - which Apple then censored entirely.

Comment: From what I tried you should remove the leading "/" from the mounted dir. For example the  synthetic.conf line would be <dir>⇥System/Volumes/Data/<dir>