# Change icons on macOS Big Sur

Tags: macos, terminal, big-sur

I wanted to change the icons on Big Sur and ran into the same problems. I tried to follow the steps here (https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/395509/387852) but on step 6:

```
sudo mount -o nobrowse -t apfs DISK_PATH MOUNT_PATH
```

I ran into this issue

```
mount_apfs: volume could not be mounted: Resource busy
mount: /Users/timrupp/newicons failed with 75
```

I really am no programmer or have any real clue how to use Terminal. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: What do you mean by „the same problems“?

Comment: Resource busy suggests something is running in the directory `/Users/timrupp/newicons`, for example did run your `sudo` command from there?  If so, then do `cd ~ ; sudo mount` etc.

Comment: I have yet to try **macOS Big Sur** because I don't waste time on beta products anymore, however, I'd attempt to replace icons from **Terminal** while still in **macOS Recovery**.

Comment: @user3439894 you need to bless the snapshot afterwards for Big Sur to boot. Maybe I'll write a tutorial for it sometime.

Comment: @Skeleton Bow, Does selecting the **Startup Disk** from **macOS Recovery** _bless_ it? A tutorial would be nice. However, I'm not moving to **macOS Big Sur** until at least **11.0.3** (if then, I wait and see hot things go).

Comment: @user3439894 I just saw that there are some instructions to bless it in the link the OP posted. I haven't tried it personally but it looks like what I found in my research back in the early stages of Big Sur. I've been looking forward to figuring out how to change icons on Big Sur (and possibly write a neat script to do so semi-automatically, since you can apparently only change system files while in recovery). However, I haven't had the time to do so yet ;P I think I'll answer this question when I have. It should definitely be by the time of Big Sur's release because I want me own icons

Answer (score -3):

`diskutil unmountDisk force DISK_PATH` (or whatever your disk is)