# BigSur installed on virtual box does not allow me to install virtual guest addition

Tags: macos, virtualization, virtualbox, big-sur

I'm trying to install guest additions on BigSur on a virtual machine.
I'm following this guideline: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41691803/how-to-install-guest-addition-in-mac-os-as-guest-and-windows-machine-as-host but the command to access recovery mode gives me operation not permitted:

[image]

There is a way to access recovery mode from a virtual box machine maybe simulating `cmd+r` inserting? Or there is another way to install guest additions?

Comment: What do the support pages for VirtualBox recommend?

Comment: @nohillside I found nothing from virtualbox documentation

Comment: There is a rather active community forum at https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewforum.php?f=22&sid=458c967a0f4cc48233de4d56175d3ec2

Comment: and it *could be* that they don't have a guest additions package compatible with macOS 11 or that even VBox itself is not fully compatible. Your best bet on this is in the VBox forums like @nohillside mentioned.

Comment: Perhaps attach a recovery partition image to the VM and boot from there? You probably have a recovery partition dmg in your recovery partition.

Comment: @JoyJin I still have the same iso from where I installed the operating system and I tried to mount it again but the only thing that spawn is a primitive shell and I can’t do anything from there

Comment: @JoyJin but doing this does not solve the problem because once the operating system is installed booting the iso shows only a primitive shell. Anyway, I'll take a look.

Comment: Or alternatively, try the method I suggested, which is slightly different from what you did. See if that makes any difference.

Comment: @JoyJin that's what I get: https://i.imgur.com/Ox70CtO.png

Comment: If your problem is booting to recovery mode, then simply create a virtual USB bootable installer for macOS Big Sur and boot from that.

Comment: Unfortunately, entering the command `sudo mount -uw` fails even with SIP disable under Big Sur. When you reach this point, you may want to update your question.

Comment: @DavidAnderson You're right I reached that point. Anyway I followed what this guy wrote here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/395508/mount-root-as-writable-in-big-sur and with this trick file system is writable. There is a way to install guest addition manually once mounted the file system?

Comment: Here's a follow-up topic: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=22&t=100903