# Mac OS 12.3+ /usr/bin/python requirement

Tags: mac, big-sur, python, monterey

[As of macOS 12.3, Apple no longer ships Python 2](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos-release-notes/macos-12_3-release-notes)

However, I am trying to install a program (.pkg installer) that depends on `/usr/bin/python` and it fails. In `/var/log/install.log` I see this error:

```
/usr/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I've already installed Python 2.7 on my system, but the root directory is now read-only so I can't symlink to `/usr/bin/python`. Disabling SIP does not work. I know there are [workarounds for mounting the root system as writable](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/395508/can-i-mount-the-root-system-filesystem-as-writable-in-big-sur), but that seems like a lot of work given that I need this for a one-time install.

So my question is, is there any other way that I can make the Python binary accessible to the installer via `/usr/bin/python`?

Comment: Really, the correct answer is for the application developer to fix their broken installer, that depends on absolute paths.  SIP doesn't have anything to do with the SSV.

Comment: @MarcWilson yea in this case it was the classic shebang on a .py file `#!/usr/bin/python`

Comment: The correct answer should also be for the app developer to stop using software that was end of life over 2 years ago. I wonder what other security issues the app has?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ended up solving this by modifying the .pkg myself. The process was:

- `pkgutil --expand` to expand the .pkg file into a folder
- Find + replace `/usr/bin/python` with the correct path to the python interpreter (in my case it was `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python`)
- `pkgutil --flatten` to convert the modified folder back into a .pkg
- install the new .pkg

Comment: Probably simpler to use `/usr/bin/env python`, which will use whatever python is installed, wherever it is.